# How would I use a rotary encoder without housing?

Tags: encoder, rotary

I'm looking to buy a rotary encoder and I've stumbled upon this:

[image]

which I assume is an encoder stripped of its housing.
My question is how would I use it? There is no shaft to turn, so I'm assuming I would need to buy the housing separately, which probably would affect accuracy.
It is however much cheaper than standard encoders and has a great resolution.

EDIT:
It is an AS5600 as seen
[on this site](https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/AS5600-absolute-value-encoder-Encoder-set-PWM-i2c-Interface-accuracy-12bit-Brushless-yuntai-motor-AS5600-magnetic/32916822164.html?spm=a2g17.10010108.1000016.1.59bd5e6bc1s6oy&isOrigTitle=true) or
[this site](https://pl.aliexpress.com/item/2PCS-AS5600-absolute-encoder-code-set-PWM-i2c-interface-precision-12bit-brushless-PTZ-motor/32921945448.html?spm=a2g17.10010108.1000016.1.f0912d59JfU1QJ&isOrigTitle=true).

Comment: Don't assume: look at the datasheet.

Comment: Try and find the data sheet of the IC. It could be a hall-sensor (magnetic field detector) with additional circuitry to works as an encoder. Although the contacts at the top suggest otherwise.

Comment: This is a magnetic encoder (similar to [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Code-disc-AS5048A-magnetic-encoder-PWM-SPI-interface-precision-14bit-brushless-holder-motor-360-contact-Angle/32916786515.html)). You will need a magnet mounted on your rotating part such that it will be above the sensor. It's a mechanical design.

Comment: please add the part number from the chip to your question .... the image is unclear ........... for future reference, provide all information in your question if you want a speedy answer

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's an [AS5600](https://ams.com/as5600). You just need a magnet positioned above it, there are Hall sensors inside, that are compared for strength in two axes and the position calculated (the arctan of the ratio of the two).

There's an eval kit from the manufacturer, which shows the mechanical arrangement for its intended use - volume controls or rotary switches.
[image]